# Using AMPscript on Landing Pages

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page, cloudpage

I have a Landing Page in CloudPages that contains several content blocks. I want to use AMPscript, but somehow it seems as the code in the content blocks will not be executed. Not even requesting URl parameters does work:
I have

`%%[
    VAR @id
    SET @id = RequestParameter('id')
]%%`

but

```
%%[=v(@id)=]%%
```

will be empty, although my url ends on `?id=myID`.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to print the variable using

```
%%=v(@id)=%%
```

And not

```
%%[=v(@id)=]%%
```

Comment: Wow, that was simple, thank you. But I still have the impression that the script doesn't run correctly. Calling functions like `RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Subscription__c', 'Id, Contact__c', 'Contact__c', '=', @id)` or `LookupRows('Subscription__c_Salesforce', 'Contact__c', @id)`  still doesn't work and leaves me with a blank screen (not even 500 Internal Error, but literally blank). Any more suggestions? :(

Comment: Please add a new question and provide fuller view of ampscript. @Guest9875